# How to do same string split using split() instead of re.findall

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

I want to split the string `'Jun1990'` into `['Jul', '1990']` using Python's `.split()` function (not regex) because `re` doesn't work properly on my AWS Linux instance.

I used below code to split the month and year by using regex but I can't figure out how to do it using only `.split()`.

```
x = 'Jul1990'
import re
zz = re.findall(r'(\w+?)(\d+)', x)
```

Comment: If you have dates in the format "%b%Y" then you can slice string by getting month as month=x[:3] and year as year=x[3:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pattern is consistent, i.e. `<Month-shortname><Year-with-century>`, then you could use string slicing instead.

```
>>> x = 'Jul1990'
>>> zz = x[:-4], x[-4:]
>>> zz
('Jul', '1990')
>>> x = 'Sept1990'
>>> zz = x[:-4], x[-4:]
>>> zz
('Sept', '1990')
```

Answer (score 0):

If pattern has alpha's and then numeric or vice-versa (unknown lengths):

```
int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, s)))
1990

''.join(filter(str.isalpha, s))
'july'
```